# Sharing folders from CentOS 5.2

Tags: centos, network-share

I need to set up a CentOS 5.2 machine with some shared folders so that they can be seen and used for read and write operations from Windows machines on the same network. The Windows machines will need to be able to perform basic file and folder operations on the folders shared by the CentOS machine: create, open, read, write, rename and delete filed, as well as create, rename and delete subfolders.

I have no experience whatsoever with CentOS. Is this functionality included with CentOS, or do I need to install some additional software? In that case, what software package would you suggest I should use to accomplish this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to install and configure samba - samba is a SMB/CIFS server which will let your Windows machines access your server.

It also comes with a fairly useful web-based config tool called 'SWAT'.

Comment: Thanks, James. Where can I get Samba?

Comment: It's in the repos; yum install samba should get it for you.